# Code::Blocks: Fortran EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE The specified path does not exist

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

I am trying to use EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE (Fortran) in Code::Blocks to start a program through a shortcut with the Windows command prompt. I have checked the path and the syntax several times, and everything is correct, however whenever I compile and run the code, when the script reaches this command I get an error saying that "The specified path does not exist. Check the path and then try again.".
Even more peculiar is the fact that, using the exact same command within the EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE directly in the command prompt successfully launches the application with no problems whatsoever.
The command I use is the following:

```
CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE("start C:\Users\dimpa\Desktop\Giannako\Optimization\VBA\SLDA.lnk")
```

I run Windows 10, Code::Blocks 20.03 and have the MinGW compiler for Fortran.

Have also used SYSTEM with exactly the same results. Also, if it is to any use helping me figure out what is going on, this command works just fine:

```
CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE("start C:\Users\dimpa\Desktop\Giannako\Optimization\VBA")
```

Opening the folder VBA to my File Explorer. The problem seems to be related with opening the shortcut of the application. Further more, opening files located in dimpa\Appdata folder (original .exe, not the shortcut) seems to be working even through the IDE, where anything in Program files is inaccessible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea but I recommend avoiding the backslashes `\`` everywhere. Windows understands forward slashes `/` without any problem. Backslashes may be interpreted as escaping characters unpredictably. Try `start C:/Users/dimpa/Desktop/Giannako/Optimization/VBA/SLDA.lnk`

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for your reply. I tried replacing backslashes with forward ones in Code::Blocks, got exactly the same message. Typed it directly in cmd, worked like a charm. It seems for some reason that the path is inaccessible or unrecognizable by Code::Blocks or the script itself. I don't think it's due to admin privileges, as I have tried opening the IDE as admin and running the code to no effect. Maybe something happens during compiling? I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers, after endless experimentation, I seem to have found a workaround.

The problem was revolving around spaces being included in the path of the original program of the shortcut in use. Apparently the compiler isn't fond of executing shortcuts, which might initially not contain spaces in the initial path, but when redirected to the original program can run into all sorts of things.

The shortcut that I was trying to execute contained a path leading into Program Files and opened an additional addon to be executed in the aforementioned program ("/m"). After realizing that trying to run a shortcut with a 150 string length target could complicate things, I directly entered the target of the shortcut into the Windows cmd, which worked perfectly fine and was much more easier to dissect and be examined in order to properly write the code:

```
CALL SYSTEM(""Full Path to Program" "/m" "Full Path to Addon"")
```

Hope this helps someone facing similar issues!